# How to extract overlay icon or its path from file in windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-shell

We have an icon overlay extension which displays different overlays depending on the file status. For automated tests, i am searching for a to check if the correct overlay is displayed. Therefore, i ask if it is possible to extract the overlay icon itself or maybe get the path to the icon for comparing.

I tried following code:

```cs
SHFILEINFO shfi = new SHFILEINFO();
IntPtr result = SHGetFileInfo(filePath, 0, ref shfi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shfi), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON | SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX);

if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    int overlayIndex = shfi.iIcon >> 24; 
    Console.WriteLine($"Overlay Index: {overlayIndex}");

    DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);
}
```

Despite the `overlayIndex` is 0 every time, is there a way to get the overlay icon without the main icon to compare or check?

EDIT:
I tried following method after Jimi's comment:

```
private static Icon GetOverlay(string filePath)
{
    var imageListGuid = new Guid("46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950");
    IMAGELIST sysImageList;
    var result = SHGetImageList(SHIL_SMALL, ref imageListGuid, out sysImageList);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        var shfi = new SHFILEINFO();
        var hSuccess = SHGetFileInfo(filePath, 0, ref shfi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shfi), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON);

        if (hSuccess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var iconIndex = shfi.iIcon;
            var overlayIndex = iconIndex & 0xF;

            var hOverlayIcon = ImageList_GetIcon(sysImageList.handle, overlayIndex, 0);
            var overlay = Icon.FromHandle(hOverlayIcon);

            return overlay;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately i never get the overlay icon, it is some kind of standard icon.

Comment: Why `shfi.iIcon >> 24`? -- You can call `SHGetImageList()` to get the `IImageList` interface, then pass the Icon's index to its `GetIcon()` method to retrieve the current Icon at that index in the System ImageList

Comment: @Jimi can you please have a look on my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IImageList::GetOverlayImage method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commoncontrols/nf-commoncontrols-iimagelist-getoverlayimage), here is a full sample:

```
static void Main()
{
    var info = new SHFILEINFO();
    SHGetFileInfo(@"c:\temp\my.lnk", FileAttributes.Normal, ref info, Marshal.SizeOf(info), SHGFI.SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI.SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX);
    DestroyIcon(info.hIcon); // file + overlay, we don't need it

    // per doc: upper eight bits of the iIcon member 
    var overlayIndex = info.iIcon >> 24; // overlayIndex >= 1 and <= 15 (system limit)
    if (overlayIndex > 0)
    {
        // change size of required icon with SHIL parameter (JUMBO is 256x256)
        SHGetImageList(SHIL.SHIL_LARGE, typeof(IImageList).GUID, out var list);
        if (list != null)
        {
            list.GetOverlayImage(overlayIndex, out var imageIndex);
            if (imageIndex >= 0)
            {
                list.GetIcon(imageIndex, ILD.ILD_NORMAL, out var hicon);
                if (hicon != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    using (var bmp = Bitmap.FromHicon(hicon))
                    {
                        bmp.Save("Overlay" + overlayIndex + ".png");
                        DestroyIcon(hicon);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, FileAttributes dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, int cbSizeFileInfo, SHGFI uFlags);

[DllImport("shell32")]
private static extern int SHGetImageList(SHIL iImageList, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IImageList ppv);

[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public int dwAttributes;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
}

public enum SHIL
{
    SHIL_LARGE = 0,
    SHIL_SMALL = 1,
    SHIL_EXTRALARGE = 2,
    SHIL_SYSSMALL = 3,
    SHIL_JUMBO = 4,
}

[Flags]
public enum ILD
{
    ILD_NORMAL = 0x00000000,
    ILD_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000001,
    ILD_MASK = 0x00000010,
    ILD_IMAGE = 0x00000020,
    ILD_ROP = 0x00000040,
    ILD_BLEND25 = 0x00000002,
    ILD_BLEND50 = 0x00000004,
    ILD_OVERLAYMASK = 0x00000F00,
    ILD_PRESERVEALPHA = 0x00001000,
    ILD_SCALE = 0x00002000,
    ILD_DPISCALE = 0x00004000,
    ILD_ASYNC = 0x00008000,
    ILD_SELECTED = ILD_BLEND50,
    ILD_FOCUS = ILD_BLEND25,
    ILD_BLEND = ILD_BLEND50,
}

[ComImport, Guid("46eb5926-582e-4017-9fdf-e8998daa0950"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public partial interface IImageList
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int Add(IntPtr hbmImage, IntPtr hbmMask, out int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int ReplaceIcon(int i, IntPtr hicon, out int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetOverlayImage(int iImage, int iOverlay);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Replace(int i, IntPtr hbmImage, IntPtr hbmMask);

    [PreserveSig]
    int AddMasked(IntPtr hbmImage, uint crMask, out int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Draw(ref int pimldp);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Remove(int i);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIcon(int i, ILD flags, out IntPtr picon);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetImageInfo(int i, out int pImageInfo);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Copy(int iDst, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punkSrc, int iSrc, uint uFlags);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Merge(int i1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punk2, int i2, int dx, int dy, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Clone([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetImageRect(int i, IntPtr prc);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIconSize(out int cx, out int cy);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetIconSize(int cx, int cy);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetImageCount(out int pi);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetImageCount(uint uNewCount);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetBkColor(uint clrBk, out uint pclr);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetBkColor(out uint pclr);

    [PreserveSig]
    int BeginDrag(int iTrack, int dxHotspot, int dyHotspot);

    [PreserveSig]
    int EndDrag();

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragEnter(IntPtr hwndLock, int x, int y);

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragLeave(IntPtr hwndLock);

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragMove(int x, int y);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetDragCursorImage([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punk, int iDrag, int dxHotspot, int dyHotspot);

    [PreserveSig]
    int DragShowNolock(bool fShow);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDragImage(IntPtr ppt, IntPtr pptHotspot, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppv);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetItemFlags(int i, out uint dwFlags);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetOverlayImage(int iOverlay, out int piIndex);
}

[Flags]
public enum SHGFI
{
    SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100,
    SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200,
    SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x000000400,
    SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800,
    SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000,
    SHGFI_EXETYPE = 0x000002000,
    SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000,
    SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000008000,
    SHGFI_SELECTED = 0x000010000,
    SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED = 0x000020000,
    SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000,
    SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001,
    SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002,
    SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004,
    SHGFI_PIDL = 0x000000008,
    SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010,
    SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS = 0x000000020,
    SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX = 0x000000040,
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help and the code example.
I successfully tested your code with an icon overlay from OneDrive. Works like a charme. 
Unfortunately when testing with our own icon overlay extension (i can see the overlay in windows explorer) everytime the overlay index returned from SHGetFileInfo is 0. Do you have an idea why this is the case?

Comment: Not sure... can you try to call this before calling SHGetFileInfo? https://gist.github.com/smourier/f1a917165d171030a6b44e1b0c4a9bb9 or can I test your overlays?

Comment: (mgr.LoadNonloadedOverlayIdentifiers() returns 0

Comment: Additionally had a look into the IconOverlayExtension, within IconOverlayExtension::GetOverlayInfo *pdwFlags = ISIOI_ICONFILE | ISIOI_ICONINDEX;
and *pIndex = 0; is set.

Comment: 0 means "ok". This works fine https://gist.github.com/smourier/bc68c3d38e8cf182e3544999dd77b0f4 but it doesn't mean the system will use every item which is reported with this code since there are limits, priorities, reserved, etc. Is there a way we can test your overlays?

Comment: Thank you for your code. For my identifiers i get an exception within this line: identifier = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IShellIconOverlayIdentifier;
This leads to {"The COM class factory for the component with CLSID {xxx} could not be retrieved due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (exception of HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."}.
It seems that there is something wrong with the registration of our IconOverlayExtension. Do you have an idea what could been went wrong. 
Nevertheless i accept your answer as the problem is caused by our code.

Comment: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG literally means "class not registered". It means what you have done to the registry (hopefully you have done something) is not working, there can be many causes, for example a 32bit vs 64bit issue. You can use procmon filter by registry access and your .exe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: If i see correctly the registration process contains writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers the friendly name, value unique identifier and to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID unique identifier, value file path to the .dll and ThreadingModel apartment. Did we miss some steps?

Comment: InprocServer32 ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inprocserver32

Comment: Sorry, yes, InprocServer32 is set beneath HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{unique identifier}.
Path to our .dll, ThreadingModel = Apartment

Comment: Additionally, i registered following example icon overlay extension: https://github.com/apriorit/IconOverlayHandler
After registering with regsvr32 ShellExtensionExample.dll using your code to get the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier object via GUID it leads to the same error HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)
The overlay extension itself is working as expected.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine with my C# test code. I don't know what test you're doing, but you must be making some mistake. Make sure C# is compiled with the same bitness as the overlay dll (ie all 64 or all 32).

Comment: Just to clarify, did you installed the icon overlay extension from https://github.com/apriorit/IconOverlayHandler and your code worked and you could get the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier of it?

Comment: I installed it and my code works (it retrieves a IShellIconOverlayIdentifier using the CLSID)

Comment: In a virtual machine, the icon overlay extension from Github is fully recognized by your code. With our icon overlay extension (and without wanting to repeat myself, it works and displays the overlays in Explorer) I now get the following error message with Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IShellIconOverlayIdentifier: interface is not supported 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)
Do you have an idea why this error is now thrown?

Comment: That could be a COM threading issue, ie: you call an object method on a different thread than the one you created it with.